# replaceFirst in a regex with $1 - JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string, regexp-replace

I need to extract the following pattern from a string and return one of the possible matches according to the input.

I used regular expressions, through different possibilities and I have not managed to get the expected result:

**input a):**
`71346 G249 USD 70045620 27/08/2020 001 / 004`

**input b):**
`71346 G249 USD 70045620/2020 27/08/2020 001 / 004`

Try one

```
String result = data.replaceFirst ( "(.*?([0-9]{6,}\\/[0-9]{4}).*)|(.*?([0-9]{6,}).*)", "$1" );
```

Try two

```
String result = data.replaceFirst ( ".*?([0-9]{6,}\\/[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{6,}).*", "$1" );
```

Try three

```
String result = data.replaceFirst ( ".*?([0-9]{6,})([0-9]{6,}\\/[0-9]{4}).*", "$1" );
```

Expected result according to input:

**input a):**
`70045620`

**input b):**
`70045620/2020`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an alternation with capturing groups in that way will give you different groupnumbers depending on the data. If you want a single group in the replacement, you can make the second part optional.

```
String[] strings = { 
    "71346 G249 USD 70045620 27/08/2020 001 / 004",
    "71346 G249 USD 70045620/2020 27/08/2020 001 / 004"
};
String regex = "^.*?\\b([0-9]{6,}(?:/[0-9]{4})?)\\b.*$";

for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.println(s.replaceFirst(regex, "$1"));
}
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/IB3hC2)

**Output**

```
70045620
70045620/2020
```

---

You could also find the match instead of using replaceFirst.

```
\b[0-9]{6,}(?:/[0-9]{4})?
```

For example

```
String[] strings = { 
    "71346 G249 USD 70045620 27/08/2020 001 / 004",
    "71346 G249 USD 70045620/2020 27/08/2020 001 / 004"
};
String regex = "\\b[0-9]{6,}(?:/[0-9]{4})?";    
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);    

for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

See another [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Erf8PF)

**Output**

```
70045620
70045620/2020
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using `String#replaceAll` here as:

```java
String[] inputs = { "71346 G249 USD 70045620 27/08/2020 001 / 004",
                    "71346 G249 USD 70045620/2020 27/08/2020 001 / 004" };
for (String input : inputs) {
    String match = input.replaceAll(".*\\b(\\d{8}(?:/\\d{4})?)\\b.*", "$1");
    System.out.println(input + " => " + match);
}
```

This prints:

```
71346 G249 USD 70045620 27/08/2020 001 / 004 => 70045620
71346 G249 USD 70045620/2020 27/08/2020 001 / 004 => 70045620/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would avoid using regex for this.
It seems like you just want the fourth word. Something like string.split() would probably be fine:

```
import java.io.*; 

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String text = "71346 G249 USD 70045620 27/08/2020 001 / 004";
        String result = text.split(" ")[3];
        System.out.print(result); 
     }
}
```

The above program will output: `70045620` for the first input and `70045620/2020` for the second.